# using bootstrap4 example for dashboard

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm learning html design with latest bootstrap4 release. I'm working off of dashboard example given on the site [Bootstrap4 dashboard](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/#), but I'm not sure how to add footer to the page which will always stays at the bottom of the window.

Comment: You should consider adding the relevant code to backup your issue, as well as any options you have already tried, in the docs you have the `fix-bottom` class for this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fixed ("sticky") footer the simplest method is probably CSS.

You can set up your HTML footer like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Body HTML Stuff...
    </body>
    <footer class="footer">
        © 2019 Your LLC. All rights reserved.
    </footer>
</html>
```

And your CSS like this:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The CSS "position: fixed" property is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

*(If this isn't clear please comment and I'll try to clarify. I'm a new contributer so I may not be explaining very well.)*

Comment: This is good, although if OP wants to stick with Bootstrap classes he can use `fixed-bottom` class to the `footer` element and get the same result without custom css

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use custom css or you can also use Bootstrap4 inbuilt "fixed-bottom" class. In my opinion using the inbuilt fixed-bottom works very well.

Write footer related code with fixed-bottom class in a separate php file like footer.php and include it just before the  tag for all of your php pages.

Now you have a fixed footer for all of your website files. Making a single change in footer.php makes changes for all of your php pages.

You can see live example in w3schools : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed_bottom&stacked=h